Resolved 'net.lingala.zip4j:zip4j:2.11.5' which is not part of the dependency lock state
I have added implementation 'net.lingala.zip4j:zip4j:2.11.5'  in dependency in build.gradle file. Then when I rebuild the project an error occured:

Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
Resolved 'net.lingala.zip4j:zip4j:2.11.5' which is not part of the dependency lock state

In build.gradle file:
dependencies {
    // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")

    implementation 'net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.2.0'
    
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"

    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:17.2.0'

    implementation 'net.lingala.zip4j:zip4j:2.11.5'

    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

error output:

Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
Resolved 'net.lingala.zip4j:zip4j:2.11.5' which is not part of the dependency lock state

Can anyone give any idea whats going wrong? I cannot understand the issues in the error.
Note: I am using react-native-zip-archive in a react-native project. After adding the  react-native-zip-archive in my react-native project and when I rebuild the android app, the above mentioned error occurred. Then I added implementation 'net.lingala.zip4j:zip4j:2.11.5' to the gradle.build. But error is still occurring.
